# Python: searching within a list

Tags: python

Given an explicit list that comprises of sets that contain elements in each of them, how can I check whether a specific element is in the list or not? It is supposed to be only one line of code.

For example: `X` is a list. It contains sets `A`, `B` and `C`. Assume set `A` contains `{x, y, z}`, `B` contains `{l, m}` and `C` contains `{o, p}`. If I were to check whether `x` is in the list, how must I do it?

Comment: _"It is supposed to be only one line of code"_ - this smells of homework

Comment: I hate sentences like "it is supposed to be one line"... it is supposed to be good code, that's it.

Comment: It isn't. It's some pseudocode that my friend has been trying to crack. According to her peers, it is one line of code.

Comment: `any(x in set_ for set_ in X)`?

Comment: I know how to do it for "multiple" lines of code by using loops. It's fairly straightforward. If there is space to write only one line of code, that's something I can't get.

Comment: @KobiK to avoid shadowing the built-in `set`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One approach can be to build a set containing the elements of all the sets in the list and check for existence of the element in this *super set*:

```
l = [{1},{2,3},{4,5}]
if 3 in {x for s in l for x in s}:
    print("Here you are!")
```

As you can see above, with set comprehension you can perform your check in just one line and in a quite pythonic way:

```
3 in {x for s in l for x in s}
```

Comment: Just to note an alternative to the set-comp is `3 in set.union(*l)` (but glglgl has already covered that one I see...)

Answer (score 1):

I guess the line is `any(x in s for s in l)` like in

```
>>> l = [{1, 2, 3}, {4, 5}, {6}]
>>> x = 5
>>> any(x in s for s in l)
True
```

It has the added  benefit on not creating new instances, not touching further sets after `x` is found and it does not depend on the fact that `l` contains sets (it could be anything iterable as well).

Answer (score 1):

```
x = [set((1, 2, 3)), set((4, 5)), set((6, 7))]
print set.union(*x)
print 1 in set.union(*x)
print 8 in set.union(*x)
```

creates a set of the union of all present sets. Using this, checking for presence is trivial.